# How to find overlapping areas?

Tags: java

the goal is to find all the rectangles you get when you come from all sides (north, west, east, south) in an orthogonal polygon. However, I can't get any further on concrete implementation.

So here is what I've done so far.

First: I have a list of coordinates (in a XML file), I want to read them into Java to determine the points and the edges of the polygon.

So now coming to my main problem. I want to find all rectangles that lie within this polygon,
[![the polygon]starting from all sides (north, east, south, west). I have a problem with this step. It occurred to me to use a SweepLine algorithm, but I am unsure how to implement it to get the desired result (overlapping rectangles coming from all sides). For that I have painted those pictures to clarify what I mean. If you come from the north edges of the polygon you would find the green rectangles. [![rectangles in the polygon coming from the north edges]
If you come from the west edges of the polygon you would find the red rectangles. 
[rectangles in the polygon coming from the west edges]
and with that the overlapping rectangles..
[overlap of green and red rectangles]
However, I'm not sure how to do this the most easiest way. I researched a lot sweep line Algorithms, but I'm not sure how to implement it and whether this is an efficient way. My goal is to find those rectangles and save them in a proper way so that I can use them for further steps (e.g. finding positions in the polygon where many rectangles overlap)

Maybe someone could help me with that. Would appreciate this a lot!

Comment: Do you just want to count them? Are they allowed to overlap? If so you could just draw lines from all inward directed corners to the next edge of the polygon. Then you could count the number of times those lines have cut another one and add that to the amount of the other corners of the original polygon. Then divide that by 4 and that should be it I think.

Comment: Thank you. However, it is not enough to count them, I actually need to find and save them in a container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know all the edges and have determined whether they face North, South, East or West, determining the rectangles could be done like this:

- Iterate through the edges.

  - Let's say we have a north-facing edge between (n.x1, n.y) and (n.x2, n.y). The corresponding rectangle must have its north-facing edge be the one we just looked at and its south-facing edge must, at least in part, consist of one or more south-facing edges.
  - We iterate through all south-facing edges and find the ones such that at least one point on the edge has an X coordinate within the range (n.x1, n.x2).

    - Additionally, they need to actually be south of the north-facing edge, so keep the ones where `s.y > n.y`.
  - Now, what we have left is a list of all south-facing edges that could possibly limit our rectangle's height. However, the rectangle is limited by whichever is the closest, so we simply pick the remaining south-facing edge, s, with the lowest y coordinate.
  - We now have a rectangle between (n.x1, n.y) and (n.x2, s.y).

Corresponding logic is implemented for each cardinal direction.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated! :)